# Are certain standard math fonts not supported in Tikz Picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, math-fonts

I was trying to insert a label into a node in the tikzpicture environment and I found that some math fonts are recognized while others are not. For example, node {$\mathcal{R}$} works fine but when I try node {$\mathbb{R}$} or node {$\mathfrak{R}$}, I get 'undefined control sequence' error.

How can I insert math expressions involving these fonts as labels into tikzpicture?

Comment: Please give some examples in code we can compile.

Comment: Have you loaded the `amssymb` package?

Comment: you would have exactly the same error if you used those commands without tikz, the question isn't related to tikz at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Picture of three Rs working fine]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$\mathcal{R}$};
\node at (1,0) {$\mathbb{R}$};
\node at (2,0) {$\mathfrak{R}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You probably don't have the required fonts loaded; they seem to load automatically in the amsart document class. Try `\usepackage{amsfonts}` or `\usepackage{amssymb}` in your document's preamble.

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the reason, thank you.